# Blender 4.0 "Only Selected Keyframes Handles" graph edit miss

Tags: graph-editor

Im just update my blender 2.9 > 4.0 and have missing hotkey for *Only show Selected F-Curve Keyframes*.

How can I set hotkey to it now?

Graph *Edit > View > Only Selected Keyframes Handles* is missing now.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by using Pie Menu Editor.

Just set up Stack Key, Set your key,  *Only Show Selected F-Curve Keyframes* = False.

Add item *Only Show Selected F-Curve Keyframes* = True